# Consume TCP stream and redirect it to another Sink (with Akka Streams)

Tags: scala, tcp, akka, akka-stream

I try to redirect/forward a TCP stream to another Sink with Akka 2.4.3.
The program should open a server socket, listen for incoming connections and then consume the tcp stream. Our sender does not expect/accept replies from us so we never send back anything - we just consume the stream. After framing the tcp stream we need to transform the bytes into something more useful and send it to the Sink.

I tried the following so far but i struggle especially with the part how to not sending tcp packets back to the sender and to properly connect the Sink.

```
import scala.util.Failure
import scala.util.Success

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.event.Logging
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Tcp
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing
import akka.util.ByteString
import java.nio.ByteOrder
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow

object TcpConsumeOnlyStreamToSink {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("stream-system")
  private val log = Logging(system, getClass.getName)    

  //The Sink
  //In reality this is of course a real Sink doing some useful things :-)
  //The Sink accept types of "SomethingMySinkUnderstand"
  val mySink = Sink.ignore;

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //our sender is not interested in getting replies from us
    //so we just want to consume the tcp stream and never send back anything to the sender
    val (address, port) = ("127.0.0.1", 6000)
    server(system, address, port)
  }

  def server(system: ActorSystem, address: String, port: Int): Unit = {
    implicit val sys = system
    import system.dispatcher
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    val handler = Sink.foreach[Tcp.IncomingConnection] { conn =>
      println("Client connected from: " + conn.remoteAddress)

      conn handleWith Flow[ByteString]
      //this is neccessary since we use a self developed tcp wire protocol
      .via(Framing.lengthField(4, 0, 65532, ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)) 
      //here we want to map the raw bytes into something our Sink understands
      .map(msg => new SomethingMySinkUnderstand(msg.utf8String))
      //here we like to connect our Sink to the Tcp Source
      .to(mySink) //<------ NOT COMPILING
    }


    val tcpSource = Tcp().bind(address, port)
    val binding = tcpSource.to(handler).run()

    binding.onComplete {
      case Success(b) =>
        println("Server started, listening on: " + b.localAddress)
      case Failure(e) =>
        println(s"Server could not bind to $address:$port: ${e.getMessage}")
        system.terminate()
    }

  }

  class SomethingMySinkUnderstand(x:String) {

  }
}
```

Update: Add this to your build.sbt file to get necessary deps

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-stream_2.11" % "2.4.3"
```

Comment: MIght be helpful to show your build.sbt file or at least the dependencies so others can re-create this.

Comment: added the deps above in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`handleWith` expects a `Flow`, i.e. a box with an unconnected inlet and an unconnected outlet. You effectively provide a `Source`, because you connected the `Flow` with a `Sink` by using the `to` operation.

I think you could do the following:

```
conn.handleWith(
  Flow[ByteString]
    .via(Framing.lengthField(4, 0, 65532, ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)) 
    .map(msg => new SomethingMySinkUnderstand(msg.utf8String))
    .alsoTo(mySink)
    .map(_ => ByteString.empty)
    .filter(_ => false) // Prevents sending anything back
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (and in my view cleaner) way to code it (AKKA 2.6.x), that will also emphasize of the fact, that you do not do any outbound flow, would be:

```
val receivingPipeline = Flow
  .via(framing)
  .via(decoder)
  .to(mySink)

val sendingNothing = Source.never[ByteString]()

conn.handleWith(Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(receivingPiline, sendingNothing))
```