# What is the most recommended way to capture TCP Server's output to an Akka Stream queue?

Tags: scala, tcp, akka-stream

I am experimenting with Akka Streams, with a view of understand exactly how one is supposed to consume what a TCP Server receives from a client (the server doesn't need to respond to client).

Here's a standard TCP server implementation (after applying what I understand from @heiko-seeberger 's succinct explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258405/consume-tcp-stream-and-redirect-it-to-another-sink-with-akka-streams)):

```
def runServer(system: ActorSystem, address: String, port: Int, collectingSink: Sink[ByteString,NotUsed]): Unit = {
    implicit val sys = system
    import system.dispatcher
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val handler = Sink.foreach[IncomingConnection] { conn =>
      conn.handleWith(
        Flow[ByteString]
          .via(JsonFraming.objectScanner(maximumObjectLength = 400))
          .alsoTo(collectingSink)
          .map(b => ByteString.empty)
          .filter(_ == false)
      )
    }

    val connections = Tcp().bind(address, port)
    val binding = connections.to(handler).run()

    binding.onComplete {
      case Success(b) =>
        println("Server started, listening on: " + b.localAddress)
      case Failure(e) =>
        println(s"Server could not bind to $address:$port: ${e.getMessage}")
        system.terminate()
    }
  }
```

The value that I pass as *collectingSink* parameter to the runServer() function is constructed this way:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, JsonFraming, Sink}
import akka.util.ByteString
import play.api.libs.json.Json

object DeviceDataProcessor {

      case class Readings (
                     radiationLevel: Double,
                     ambientTemp: Double,
                     photoSensor: Double,
                     humidity: Double,
                     sensorUUID: String,
                     timestampAttached: Long)

      val xformToDeviceReadings = Flow[ByteString]
        .via(JsonFraming.objectScanner(maximumObjectLength = 400))
        .map(b => {

            val jsonified = Json.parse(b.utf8String)
            val readings  =  Readings(
                           (jsonified \ "radiation_level")         .as[Double],
                           (jsonified \ "ambient_temperature")     .as[Double],
                           (jsonified \ "photosensor")             .as[Double],
                           (jsonified \ "humidity")                .as[Double],
                           (jsonified \ "sensor_uuid")             .as[String],
                           (jsonified \ "timestamp")               .as[Long]
            )
            readings
        })
        .to(Sink.queue())

    }
```

Finally, this is how I run my Driver:

```
object ConsumerDriver extends App {
       val actorSystem = ActorSystem("ServerSide")
       TCPServer.runServer(actorSystem,"127.0.0.1", 9899,DeviceDataProcessor.xformToDeviceReadings)
}
```

I am failing to grasp the reasoning behind two things here:

1) The type of *xformToDeviceReadings* is derived as

```
Sink[ByteStream,NotUsed]
```

Shouldn't the mapped type *Readings* appear here?

2) How do I begin to read from this queue and pass the elements into another upstream flow? Should I have to materialize first and then use the materialized queue as my new *Source*?

I have gone through the documentation at Akka site. But, I will be happy to be redirected to any specific portion of this document, or other posts on SO.

Please help me plug the gap in my concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** the type is `Sink[ByteString,NotUsed]` as Akka Streams is left biased when composing materialized values. This means that the materialized value exposed by your combined sink (`xformToDeviceReadings`) is the one coming from its first stage (a `map`, which materializes to `NotUsed`).

To expose the materialized value you want you need to change to

```
...
.toMat(Sink.queue())(Keep.right)
```

Note that the type of your Sink now changes to `Sink[ByteString, SinkQueueWithCancel[Readings]]`

**2)** to interact with your queue of `Readings` you need to run your stream, hence obtaining your materialized value (the queue) and start pulling items from it. This could happen in the connection handling:

```
val handler: Sink[IncomingConnection, Future[Done]] = Flow[IncomingConnection]
  .map { conn =>
    conn.handleWith(
      Flow[ByteString]
        .via(JsonFraming.objectScanner(maximumObjectLength = 400))
        .alsoToMat(collectingSink)(Keep.right)
        .map(_ => ByteString.empty)
        .filter(_ == false)
    )
  }
  .mapAsync(1){ queue ⇒
    queue.pull()
  }
  .toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.right)
```

Note that the solution above is not ideal, especially because the materialized queue is most likely **not** thread safe. If your purpose is to plumb these `Readings` to some other downstream flow, you better directly connect a `Sink` fit for the purpose, instead of going through a queue.

Comment: many thanks for the explanation. The *left-biased* is a key piece of information I was unaware of.

Comment: many thanks for the explanation. The *left-biased* is a key piece of information I was unaware of. However, I am a bit confused about the point of thread-unsafe nature of the queue. Your point on the requirement of downstream plumbing, is correct. I intend to pass a 'Sink' as a parameter to runServer(), which should work as a piece of hand-off mechanism: queue, to me, is a natural choice. Now, going by your words of caution, I am exploring other possibilities. But, when people use queues, what do they do?

Comment: I don't know what you ultimately want to do with these `Readings` so a queue might as well be a good choice in your case. Just keep in mind, if you're choosing this Sink, to always use the queue from the same thread.